# Overnight Index Swaps

Tags: swaps, overnight-index

Just a very quick general question regarding the OIS market. Is it common place on termsheets to state a PV Notional and additionally a FV notional, if so what is the purpose of this and does market convention stipulate whether PV of FV notional should be booked?

Most swaps I have dealt with previously, like IRS & Commodity Swaps, have generally always had one notional on both Fixed and Floating legs.

Appreciate any comments.

Comment: Isn't this a discount quoting convention as with repos? ie - this is how the yield is quoted

Comment: Have you seen this? Which notional was being used for cashflow calculations if they were different?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies. Broker is quoting based on the PV notional and Dealers dealt on a FV basis which is wrong. Problem solved.